# Getting the most recent record for each unique user in Parse using PFQuery

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com, and have two classes: `User` and `Report`. A `User` may issue several reports during a day, but I'm only interested in the most recent one. However, I need to get all the reports that meet specific criteria, but only the most recent one.

The end result is an array of `Report`s, where the `User` is unique on each one, something like this:

```
ObjectId | ReportedValue | User | CreatedAt
1234     | 100           | aaaa | 2013-05-20T04:23:41.907Z
1235     | 100           | bbbb | 2013-04-29T05:10:41.907Z
1236     | 100           | cccc | 2013-05-20T02:14:41.907Z
1237     | 100           | dddd | 2013-05-19T04:03:41.907Z
```

So, `User` aaaa might have 20 reports, but I only need the most recent, for each user. However, I'm searching based on the `ReportedValue` being `100`, and the desired result is the report objects, not the user, so I'd prefer not to go through every user.

Is this possible in Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using another object in the data model to assist with this. It would basically be a container with a relationship to `Report`. When any new report is saved, a bit of `cloud code` runs which:

1. Finds the previous latest `Report` for the associated user
2. Removes that report from the container relation
3. Adds the new report to the container relation

Working this way, your app can make a single, simple, query on the relation to get all of the latest `Report`s.

Comment: This is actually closer to what I ended up doing, though technically the other answer from Robert is "correct".

Answer (score 1):

From Rest API.... works providing the user's OID is in the ACL segment in the records in the Class you are querying.

in addition to the other predicate of your query, parse can limit the number of returned rows..

```
  --data-urlencode 'limit=1' \
  --data-urlencode 'skip=0' \
```

For the user, if you GET the row from user table for the user you are querying
and the 'token' field value for that user and  then with your report query, Set an extra header to the sessionToken value you will get ONLY THAT User's report objects.

```
-H "X-Parse-Session-Token: pn..." \
```

you will get just that user's reports

AND

results.size = 1